# Datatables uncaught reference error with django

Tags: jquery, datatable

Hi i'm using datatable in a django/python app,

i have an index page that load a list from a DB and put it in a datatable.

Since this morning i have an error that start with :

TypeError : C is undefined

(that seem to point on the line where i define the datatable)

and then of course this error pop everytime the setInterval is called on this tab :

ReferenceError : oTable is undefined

My view :

```
def index(request):
    listOPT = []
    Data = []

    fluxManagerState = settings.FLUX_MANAGER_STATE
    cursor = connections['site'].cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_RESUME_MVT_INIT_ACTIF}")
        mouvements = dictfetchall(cursor)
    finally:
        cursor.close()   
    return render(request, 'index.html', locals())
```

Function that works with ajax to refresh the datatable :

```
def listMVTinit(request):
    cursor = connections['site'].cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_RESUME_MVT_INIT_ACTIF}")
        data = dictfetchall(cursor)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json")
```

My template :

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Liste Mouvement initiaux</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 12 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="{% static 'css/Gestion_Mouvements.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/base/jquery-ui.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"  media="all">
<link href="{% static 'css//bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css' %}" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/fnReloadAjax.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js' %}"></script>


<script>
   function getPeseeSilo(){
                  var req = $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'getPeseeSilo' %}",
                dataType: "json",
                  });
                                 req.done(function(tab) {
                   if(tab.Error == true){
                    console.log(tab.msg);
                   }else{
                                           window.location.replace("mouvementPeseeSilo");
                   }
                  });
        }
   function checkbridgeState(){
                           if (document.getElementById('ebFlux').value == 'False')
                              {
                                 $('#bridgeState').show();
                  var req = $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'getBridgeState' %}",
                dataType: "json",
                  });
                  req.done(function(tab) {
                   if(tab.Error == true){
                    console.log(tab.msg);
                   }else{
                    document.getElementById('ebBridgeState').value = tab['value'];          
                   }
                  });
                              }
        }
   $(document).ready(function() {
             oTable = $('#indexTab').dataTable({
                 ajax: {
                                    "url": "{% url 'listMVTinit' %}",
                                    "dataSrc": ""
                                  },
                            "columns": [
                                    { "data": "Id" },
                                    { "data": "DateHeureCreat" },
                                    { "data": "Immat_Transporteur" },
                                    { "data": "Poids_Charge" },
                                    { "data": "Sous_Type" },
                                    { "data": "Type_Mouvement" },
                                    { "data": "Libelle" },
                                    { "data": "Espece" }
                                  ],
            });
        });
                   setInterval(checkbridgeState, 1000);
        setInterval(function(){oTable.api().ajax.reload();}, 2000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wb_Shape1" style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:5px;width:1300px;height:100px;z-index:0;">
<img src="../static\images/img0001.png" id="Shape1" alt="" style="width:1300px;height:100px;"></div>
<div id="Html1" style="position:absolute;left:4px;top:105px;width:1300px;height:400px;z-index:1">
<table id="indexTab" class="center-all" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Date et heure création</th>
                <th>Véhicule</th>
                <th>Pesée 1</th>
                <th>Type mouvement</th>
                <th>Sous type</th>
                <th>Code espèce</th>
                <th>Libellé espèce</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
           {% for mouvement in mouvements %}
            <tr>
            <th>{{mouvement.Id}}</span></th>
            <th>{{mouvement.DateHeureCreat}}</span></th>
            <th>{{mouvement.Immat_Transporteur}}</span></th>
            <th>{{mouvement.Poids_Charge}}</span></th>
            <th>{{mouvement.Type_Mouvement}}</span></th>
            <th>{{mouvement.Sous_Domaine}}</span></th>
            <th>{{mouvement.Espece}}</span></th>
            <th>{{mouvement.Libelle}}</span></th>
            <th><a target="_blank" href="/gestion_mouvement/mouvementDetails/{{mouvement.Id}}"><button type="button" class="editbtn">Edit</button> <button class="deletebtn">Delete</button></a></th>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table></div>
<div id="bridgeState" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" id="ebBridgeState" style="position:absolute;left:15px;top:17px;width:900px;height:30px;line-height:30px;z-index:2;" name="ebFluxState" value="" readonly spellcheck="false">
<input type="button" id="btnPeseeSilo" onclick="getPeseeSilo();return false;" name="btnPeseeSilo" value="Pesée 1 Silo" style="position:absolute;left:936px;top:17px;width:96px;height:40px;z-index:3;">
<a target="_blank" href="/gestion_mouvement/mouvementCreation"><input type="button" id="btnCreateManual" name="btnCreateManual" value="Création Manuelle" style="position:absolute;left:1037px;top:17px;width:119px;height:40px;z-index:4;">
<input type="text" id="ebFlux" style="position:absolute;left:1191px;top:24px;width:86px;visibility:hidden;height:17px;line-height:17px;z-index:5;" name="Editbox1" value="{{fluxManagerState}}" spellcheck="false">
</body>
</html>
```

i have no idea why i suddenly got this error, i was trying to add options to my datatable settings and since then i got this issue.

Comment: hi @Girard clement : ), please add the error log

Comment: Not sure how i can give more to you than what i wrote, i saw the error on the web console and it doesn't really say more than the "TypeError : C is undefined" on the line "oTable = $('#indexTab').dataTable" and "ReferenceError : oTable is undefined" each time the " setInterval(function(){oTable.api().ajax.reload();}, 2000);"

Comment: Please show the rendered version of that oTable definition (by copying and pasting from View Source in the browser).

Comment: removed the "django" and "python" tags, it's only a javascript / jquery issue.

Answer (score 0):

`oTable` is defined in a `$(document).ready()` callback, but referenced just after (outside the callback). This is more easily spotted with a clean indentation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#indexTab').dataTable({
        ajax: {
            "url": "{% url 'listMVTinit' %}",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Id" },
            { "data": "DateHeureCreat" },
            { "data": "Immat_Transporteur" },
            { "data": "Poids_Charge" },
            { "data": "Sous_Type" },
            { "data": "Type_Mouvement" },
            { "data": "Libelle" },
            { "data": "Espece" }
        ],
    });
});
setInterval(checkbridgeState, 1000);
setInterval(function(){oTable.api().ajax.reload();}, 2000);
```

Since you didn't declared `oTable` as local (using `var oTable`) it can of course be accessed outside the `$().ready()` callback, **BUT** not before this callback has been executed. Here you reference it BEFORE the callback has been executed, so it's indeed not defined at that point.

The obvious solution is to move the `setInterval()` call within the callback (and while you're at it, making `oTable` local would be cleaner since you don't need it to be global anymore).

NB : this won't solve the "C is undefined" TypeError but since there's nowhere a reference to a variable "C" in your code there's no way to debug this without running the whole damn thing. But modern browsers all have step debuggers by now so your best bet is to put a breakpoint on this line and step into the function's code until you find the culprit.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, i tried to put the setInterval inside the .ready function but it doesn't fix my problem because there error is gone only because my setInterval aren't called when within the .ready

Comment: @Girardclément yes of course, as I mentionned this won't solve the root problem, but there's no way for us to debug this root problem with the informations you provided.

Comment: what more can i give you to solve this ? i don't even really understand that type C error, i have this page done for a while now and even yesterday the ajax and everything was working fine.

Comment: Except using your browser's developer tools (mainly the step debugger) there's not much you can do. Or do a diff between your current source and the last working commit (you're using a SCC of any sort - git, mercurial or whatever-, don't you ?) and find out what changes might have introduced this.

Comment: The only thing i changed was to try adding some options to the datatable, and since i didn't change anything else "programation" related so i think maybe this error come from an indentation issue or something like that, the problem is that i use WYSIWYG and you can't really see how stuff is indented when you add parts of HTML on your own.

Comment: Indentation is irrelevant in both html and js. And except for the two hints I gave you (using your browser's debugger, checking the diffs vs the last known working commit) there's nothing we can do.

Comment: it may be for HTML and JS, but i have been working with datatable for a while now and i have seen alot of people having errors coming frim bad syntax on the datatable definition. For example the type C error is often a mismatch between the number of columns defined on the tab and the actual number of column use. i tried the step by step but it doesn't give me more info than before, just the same error on the same lines nothing more. i can go back to my previous commit of course but this is something i need to implement so i will have to deal with it one day.